# How to execute a function when using the createGraphics function in P5js?

Tags: html5-canvas, processing, p5.js

I want to use the createGraphics function to draw something on another screen... and then paste that into my main sketch..

in the docu, the example they give is doing something like:

```javascript
var vignette;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(710, 400);
  vignette = createGraphics(400, 250);
}

function draw(){

  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 60, 60);

  pg.background(51);
  pg.noFill();
  pg.stroke(255);
  pg.ellipse(mouseX-150, mouseY-75, 60, 60);

  //Draw the offscreen buffer to the screen with image()
  image(pg, 150, 75);
}
```

But what i want to do is more complex than **pg.background(51)**

I want to run this function which creates a radial gradient:

```javascript
function drawGradient() {
  for (let r = canvasX; r > 0; --r) {
    let lightnes = map(r,0,canvasX,360,0)
    fill(360, 360, lightnes)
    ellipse(0, 0, r, r)
  }
}
```

But if i do vignette.drawGradient() i get the error: vignette.drawGradient is not a function...

So how can i then execute things like whats inside the drawgradient function inside the createGraphics function?

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/ZJjWbw?editors=0010

Comment: Btw, I noticed that you've only accepted 8 answers despite asking 28 questions. You might want to go back and accept some answers before asking more questions.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't put anything "inside" the `createGraphics()` function. The `createGraphics()` function returns an instance of `p5.Renderer`. You then call functions on that instance.

You were going in the right direction by trying to call `vignette.drawGradient()`, but like you've discovered, `p5.Renderer` does not contain a `drawGradient()` function. Only your sketch contains that function, because it's something you created.

`p5.Renderer` contains the drawing functions: stuff like `background()`, `fill()`, `rect()`, and `ellipse()`. So if you want to draw your gradient to your `vignette` renderer, you have to call the functions that actually draw things on your `vignette` variable. Like this:

```
function drawGradient() {
  for (let r = canvasX; r > 0; --r) {
    let lightnes = map(r,0,canvasX,360,0)
    vignette.fill(360, 360, lightnes)
    vignette.ellipse(0, 0, r, r)
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer but why do i get only a quarter of circle, and it looks all black and over drawn? heres my codepen: https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/gxjoxp?editors=0010 it should look like a normal radial gradient. thanks so much! :)

Comment: @GiorgioMartini Because your calls to `colorMode()` and `translate()` are on the sketch, not on the `vignette` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried what you suggested about the color mode and translate needing to be on the vignette but it still doesnt work any ideas? here's the pen: https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/gxjoxp I left another color mode in my main sketch as i also need one there..

Comment: @GiorgioMartini Now you're translating the main sketch and the vignette. I really recommend getting out a piece of paper and a pencil and drawing out exactly what each of those calls does.

Comment: I do need the main sketch to be translated... the vignette i did it, because i thought that was what you meant... But my most important concert is why the gradient looks all black. ive updated it so now only the main uses the translate function.. do you know why the gradient is not working in this version? https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/gxjoxp

Comment: @GiorgioMartini Hint: what is the stroke color of each circle you're drawing? If you have any follow-up questions, please post them in their own question. Note that this question about the circle being black has nothing to do with the vignette.